# Sharing vscode-server for multiple users to save disk space

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

We have a Linux server (Ubuntu 20.04) with ~100 users and very limited disk space. The disk quota for each user should be limited to 100MB. The access to the server is via SSH.

Several users want to use VSCode for remote development of source code (not shared) that resides on the server. They can install the remote server for VSCode, but it results in a rather large directory `.vscode-server` from 300MB and up for each user. This would fill up the disk with just a few users activating and using it.

Ideally the users could share the VSCode-server part just as they share all the other software development tools on this server. Is this possible, and how to do it?

Upgrading the server hardware/disk is not possible for the scope of this question.